# How do you make jQuery modular in a simple way?

Tags: jquery, modular

I've read some stuff after asking Dr. Google some okay examples were:

- http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-modal-tutorial/
- https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/concepts/

But how about you guys? Do you guys know any good tricks or tips to make jQuery more modular?

I'm quite new to jQuery, so I'm trying to learn a way to keep it modular, so that when I get more complex stuff, I can write code more cleanly for people to understand.

Also if you guys know any good websites that discusses or teaches a way to make jQuery modular I'd like to know :^)

Comment: We find that creating any reusable functionality as a plugin did the trick for most cases. On top of that we only use Typescript now, allowing us to write stupidly complex code without worrying about JS being a weakly-typed language. Everything is modules, interfaces and classes :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some good resources on your matter, wether you want it to be plugin-based, use modular patterns such as IIFE, or even AMD. Here's a question of mine which has a resourceful answer (by Sam0):

[Trying turn this jQuery slideShow plugin into a neat and modular "module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274390/trying-turn-this-jquery-slideshow-plugin-into-a-neat-and-modular-module)

However if you prefer not to use plugins, simply wrapping (structuring) parts of your code into separate [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)
is definitely a great start. Make sure to include your trusty jQuery initialization code for modular functionality:

```
(function($) {  
    // For plugins you may want to include:
    $.fn.pluginName = function( args ) { /* stuff goes here */ }
    // non-plugin stuff
}) (jQuery);
```

Also if you use plugins, make sure to consider including a separate *extension.js* file calling the plugins and using them, for clarity, brevity, and *modularity.* And yes, making that too a module is a **great idea.**

At first you may find this to be a little complex, but when you learn and understand it I'm sure that you'll find it to be quite simple.